# Cannot deserialize a Pipeline Stage from string

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb a agggregation pipeline stage on a string like this:

```
{ $project: { 
    txtStatus: { $trim: { input: '$txtStatus' } } 
} },            
{ $match: {$or: [{'txtStatus': {$eq: 'VALID'}},{'txtStatus': {$eq: 'NOTVALID'}}]} },
{ $group: {
    _id: '$txtStatus',
    Count: { $sum: 1 }
} }
```

I currently need to separate each of the stages and append one by one like this:

```
_myRepo.SetDatabase("MyDbName")
    .GetCollection("MayColl")
    .Aggregate<dynamic>()
    .AppendStage<dynamic>(stageProject.ToBsonDocument())
    .AppendStage<dynamic>(stageMatch.ToBsonDocument())
    .AppendStage<dynamic>(stageGroup.ToBsonDocument());
```

I need to pass the entire string to the "AppendStage" without having to split it into stages like Im doing today, something like this:

```
_myRepo.SetDatabase("MyDbName")
    .GetCollection("MayColl")
    .Aggregate<dynamic>()
    .AppendStage<dynamic>(myEntireAggregationString.ToBsonDocument());
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my query inside brackets:

```
[
    { $project: { 
        txtStatus: { $trim: { input: '$txtStatus' } } 
    } },            
    { $match: {$or: [{'txtStatus': {$eq: 'VALID'}},{'txtStatus': {$eq: 'NOTVALID'}}]} },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$txtStatus',
        Count: { $sum: 1 }
    } }
]
```

Then, I deserialized the query into a BsonDocument Array and passed this array/list in the Aggregate() method:

```
var pipelineStages = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument[]>(myQuery).ToList();

var ret = _myRepo.SetDatabase("MyDbName")
    .GetCollection("MayColl")
    .Aggregate<dynamic>(pipelineStages)
    .ToList();
```